# Мистика с выполнением js

Tags: вёрстка, html5, javascript

Итак, знакомлю вас с моим кодом.

Есть значит у меня большая кнопка:

```
<span><img onclick="open('f');" src="f.png" class="sicon" id="ficon"></span>
```

Есть див для затемнения:

```
<div id="z"></div>
```

Его css:

```
position:absolute;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:none;
```

Есть ещё одна секция:

```
<section class="sm" id="fm"><!--Куча всякой всячины--></section>
```

У неё тоже display:none

Есть функция:

```
function open(iid) {
document.getElementById('z').style.display = 'inline';
document.getElementById(iid + 'm').style.display = 'inline';
}
```

При вводе open('f'); в консоли хрома всё ок. Но когда я нажимаю на кнопку, то всё исчезает и получается белый фон. Смотрю код - там становиться пусто. Даже доктайп исчез.

В чём проблема? Как исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переименуйте обработчик, `open` - нативный метод window, нативные методы не стоит переопределять во избежание непредсказуемого поведения. По идее - должно помочь. Например:

```
<span><img onclick="openImage('f');" src="f.png" class="sicon" id="ficon"></span>
```

---

```
function openImage( iid ) {
   document.getElementById('z').style.display = 'inline';
   document.getElementById(iid + 'm').style.display = 'inline';
}
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло. p.s. А будит ли такая проблема с close?

Comment: @danpetruk - не знаю, не пробовал, но вполне возможно, зачем рисковать?

PS: метку вы четкую придумали... :D